# Отключение сигнала от лямбды

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

На en.so наткнулся на возможность отключения сигнала от лямбды таким способом:

```
QMetaObject::Connection *conn = new QMetaObject::Connection();
QSharedPointer<QMetaObject::Connection> pconn(conn);
(*pconn) = QObject::connect(my_obj, &MyClass::mySignal, [this,pconn]() {
    QObject::disconnect(*pconn);
});
```

Нет ли здесь утечки памяти и каким ещё способом возможно произвести обозначенную операцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, утечки памяти тут нет. В том виде, что Вы хотите сделать, боюсь, выбор невелик. Так или иначе, придётся использовать указатель. Альтернативой является передача `connection` в качестве аргумента сигнала либо же сохранение его в поле класса и обращение по `this` в лямбде.

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ. Видите, меня смущает то, что `QObject::connect()` возвращает объект `QMetaObject::Connection`, создаваемый в стеке, тогда как в `QSharedPointer` хранится объект, созданный в куче. В итоге производится подмена указателя на объект соединения. Тогда, по идее, объект в куче должен потеряться... Или я что-то упускаю?..

Comment: @alexis031182, упускаете то, что подмены указателя не происходит. Происходит замена того, на что указывает указатель. Сам указатель остается прежним, просто то, на что он указывал теперь имеет другие данные — те, что были им получены после выполнения `operator=(Connection && other)` класса `Connection`

Comment: Точно, Вы правы. А я глядел на переопределённые операторы самого `QSharedPointer`, упустив из виду `QMetaObject::Connection`. Спасибо.